# SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory (SQL: select * from `jobs`) 11

Tags: php, laravel

Could someone find me a fix Error is `$jobs = Job::all();`?

Shared files https://1drv.ms/f/s!AnPb5n9nCL2ipyH_Wu61GVkT-X-k

```
 <?php
 
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
 
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Job;
 
class JobController extends Controller
{
    public function index(){
  //here'$jobs = Job::all();
        return view('welcome',compact('jobs'));
    }
    public function show($id,Job $job){
        return view('jobs.show',compact('job'));
    }
}
```

Comment: can you post your `env` file

Comment: Do you actually have your code all in single quotes like that?

Comment: Please post all relevant data/code _inside_ your question here, not on 3rd party sites. Thx

Comment: Did you run `php artisan migrate` I thing you haven't run the migration command that's why you are getting this

Comment: No i don't have that in my code.

Answer (score 0):

set these 2 options in your job model, you can check official [laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent)

$table requires string value of your table name and $fillable requires an array of column names of your job table

```
protected $table
protected $fillable
```

Comment: Can you send me the full job code i use laravel 6 btw. <?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Job extends Model
{
    public function getRouteKeyName(){
     return 'slug';
    }
    public function company(){
     return $this->belongsTo('App\Company');
    }
}